Python sorted comparator
I am trying to sort a list of tuples on the lexicographic order of the sub-string that the tuples are indicating.
In the following case, I wish to sort a which actaully represents ["sd", "dce", "ces"]. I'm not sure how to use the comparator to achieve this.
def cmp(key, text):
    return text[key[0]:key[1]+1]

a = [(1,2), (2, 4), (3, 5)]
text = "asdcesa"
sorted(a, key=cmp(text))

The above code would give this error "cmp() missing 1 required positional argument: 'text'"

You could use key = lambda x: cmp(x, text), or key = functools.partial(cmp, text), but if you don't make some kind of provision to be passing key a function that takes exactly one argument, what do you expect?

A key= function must take exactly one argument. Yours requires two arguments, so can't work as-is.
There are various ways to work around that. Here's one. Good advice: until (and even after) you've become an expert, resist the temptation to try to squash this  all into one line.
text = "asdcesa"
def keyfunc(key, text=text):
    return text[key[0] : key[1]+1]

a = [(1,2), (2, 4), (3, 5)]
print(sorted(a, key=keyfunc))

# which displays
# [(3, 5), (2, 4), (1, 2)]

